# Song used in the after credits scene of Boku no Hero episode 47 with the introduction of All For One

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

On episode 47 of *Boku no Hero*, after the credits scene when All For One is introduced, there's a piano and operatic and just so chilling.

What's this song?

Answer (score 1):

that's all for one theme (you can't run) 
https://soundcloud.com/thighpocket/my-hero-academia-all-for-one-theme